# Algorithm to obtain the item(s) at a precise number

Tags: javascript, java, c#, python, algorithm

I find that algorithm/functionality in two games already, but I always wanted to know what was the logic behind it.

Basically, there is a list of items and each of them has an id.

For example:

- item_1 has id: 1
- item_2 has id: 2
- item_3 has id: 4
- item_4 has id: 8
- item_5 has id: 16
- etc.

The id is multiplied by two every new item.

There is then a number, let's say 4, that indicate what the current item is. Is this case that would be `item_3`, but the tricky part is that number could also select multiple items at once like 7 which is 4 + 2 + 1 (`item_3`, `item_2`, `item_1`) or 17 which is 16 + 1 (`item_5`, `item_1`). It can go really high like 16384 if you have a long list and still be perfectly accurate for the multiple selections.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: You put lots of language tags. Can you pick one or do you want this to be language-agnostic?

Comment: @Sweeper sorry, i want it to be language-agnostic, but if had to pick one that would be c#.

Comment: The keyword you should search for to find resources on the topic is **bit field**.

Comment: See C# [Flags](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.flagsattribute) for a bit (haha) more information. Generally known as "bit field". Imagine the numbers as bits and see which bits at which point are "set" or not. Edample: id 1: `0001`; id 4: `0100`. Combined: `0101` which is "5". So you just need to store the value `5` to know that you mean both 1 and 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorithm you described is basically outputting where the 1's are in the binary representation of the number.

For 7, its binary representation is `111`. There are three 1's: in the first, second, and third position *from the left* respectively, so it's item 1, 2 and 3. Note that we are counting from the left.

Another example:

For 10, its binary representation is `1010`. There are two 1's: in the second and fourth position *from the left*, so the output would be items 2 and 4.

Here is an implementation in C#.

```
public static List<int> FindOnes(int number) {
    var list = new List<int>();
    var binaryString = Convert.ToString(number, 2);
    for (int i = 0 ; i < binaryString.Length ; i++) {
        if (binaryString[binaryString.Length - i - 1] == '1') {
            list.Add(i + 1);
        }
    }
    return list;
}

// usage:
FindOnes(7) // [1,2,3]
```

Answer (score 1):

No idea how the games you're talking about implement it, but if this was me I would do it using bits in the binary expression of the number (example code in java).

```
public boolean isItemSelected(final int number, final int itemId) {
    return (number & (1 << (itemId - 1))) != 0;
}
```

The trick here being that the binary representation of a number (from right to left) already denotes whether 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, etc. is required additively to make the number using only powers of two.  The left shift simply makes a number which (in binary) is all 0's except a 1 in the 'itemId - 1'th slot.  The & will match if that bit is `1` in the given `number`.  And then checking that the result is *not* `0` simply turns it into a `boolean`.

Obviously you can combine this with some looping or anything else if you want to build the array/List of all the 'itemIds' which match.

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript, you could take the number, convert it to a binary value, take the bits, reverse it and take the values (index plus one) or zero for a filtering of truthy values.

```js
var value = 13,
    items = [...value.toString(2)].reverse().map((v, i) => +v && (i + 1)).filter(Boolean);

console.log(items);
```